# Hiding NULL text in attributes using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, null, qgis-3

In QGIS 3, how do I hide the 'NULL' text from empty attributes?

QGIS 2.18 has a setting for that, but can't find it in QGIS 3.4.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 6):

From `Settings -> Options -> Data Sources ->` Delete NULL text:

[image]

Before deletion:

[image]

After deletion:

[image]

Comment: Tanks. Do you know how turn grouplayers text bold and layers text no bold?

Comment: @FernandoFreitas This is a new question, and you can ask one question only at a time. If the answer solved your problem, please accept it so that it can help others.